# Dynamic Range Issue

Tags: excel, dynamic, range

I have a table like shown below. One column has the week and the other total cases for that week. The week column A has already been filled out for the year but the cases column B we manually update with the total amount of cases received when the week is closed. I would like to create a table that will automatically update when the new week is populated , but that will also graph the previous 3 weeks therefore comparing a total of 4 weeks. I cant figure out how this is done. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, type the following formula in an empty cell, let's say C2.

```
=COUNTA(B:B)-1
```

This counts the number of non-blank entries in column B, excluding the header.

Then type this in E3:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&$C$2-5+ROW())
```

And type this in F3:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&$C$2-5+ROW())
```

Just copy E3 and F3 down to row 6, then your desired table is obtained.

For your information, the `INDIRECT` function can return the content of the cell which is indicated by the argument of this function. E.g. `INDIRECT("B"&2+1)` will give the content of cell B3.